# using vb6 file print source in vb 2012

Tags: vb.net

I am new in vb 2012 and when I tried to apply VB6 source of the two differ, I've been searching in google how to use this source vb 2012 but I do not find it, anyone there who can help me how to use this source in vb 2012, the following source code is

> Dim FileTeks As String
>
> > FileTeks = App.Path & "\conn.ini"
> >
> > > > UserName = Trim(txtUserName.Text)
> > > >
> > > > Pass = Trim(txtPassword.Text)
> > > >
> > > > Server = Trim(txtServer.Text)
>
> Open FileTeks For Output As #1
>
> > > > Print #1, Enkrip(Server, 4)
> > > >
> > > > Print #1, Enkrip(UserName, 4)
> > > >
> > > > Print #1, Enkrip(Pass, 4)
>
> Close #1

thanks for the help

Comment: VB.Net is really a _whole new language_ when compared to vb6. Don't think of it as just a vb7; there's a lot more to it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code.  What happens when you try to run or compile it?

Comment: @jmoreno : i find some error in, code : open ... for and # symbols, actually, is there? which could alter the source vb6 to vb 2012, because I do not understand that change is in vb 2012 as what was said "Joel Coehoorn"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to write to file in .NET

```
Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter("FileTeks.ini", False)
        sw.WriteLine(Enkrip(Server,4))
        sw.WriteLine(Enkrip(UserName,4))
        sr.WriteLine(Enkrip(Pass,4))

        sw.Flush()
        sw.Close()
End Using
```

This assumes the output from `Enkrip` is string.  Alternatively (since it is an ini):

```
sw.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", "Server", Enkrip(Server,4))
' or
sw.WriteLine("{0} {1}", "Server =", Enkrip(Server,4))
```

You probably need the 'keys' in the clear so you can read them back again rather than encrypting the entire line.  Also you probably want to put it all in a Try/Catch so that of the filename is bad or there is an issue with permissions you can trap it.

Another alternative may be to use PInvoke to use the old Win32 Read/WritePrivateProfileString.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Using the VisualBasic package from .net you should be able to find the most of the VB6 own commands. In any case, vb.net is not a merely upgrade of vb6, it is a quite different language.

If your code base is not too big, I will recommend you to try to refactor your code. We made once one automatic conversion from vb6 to vb.net and now we regret it.